# Maximum number of members in a club

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

Some people form $n=36$ clubs. There are no two clubs with same set of club members. No two people are in the same set of clubs.

If a person is not in a club, he/she must be friend with one person in that club.

However, nobody is friend with another person in the same club (yes, a weird bunch of people).

What's the maximum possible size of a club in this setup?

This is similar to the odd town/even town problem and the Fisher inequality. I suspect we could approach in a similar linear algebra setup: [https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~panni/lec20.pdf](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Epanni/lec20.pdf)

Comment: "If a person is not in a club, he/she must be friend with one person in that club."  At least one person, or exactly one person?

Answer (score 2):

There can be at most $2^{n-1} = 2^{35}$ people in any given club $C$. That's because there are $35$ clubs other than $C$, and for every subset of those $35$ clubs (including the empty subset), at most one person can be in exactly those clubs, and also in club $C$.

As pointed out in hinkypunk's answer, we can achieve this bound. Suppose that there are $2^{36}$ people: for every subset of the $36$ clubs, there is a person exactly in those clubs. Furthermore, suppose that every person is friends with only one other person: whoever is in exactly all the clubs they are not in. Then all the conditions in the problem are satisfied, and every club contains the maximum possible amount of $2^{35}$ people.

Comment: I suppose it's *de trop* to point out that there are not quite $2^{33}$ people in the world $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Joffan How anthropocentric of you to assume all club members are human. There are approximately 10 quintillion insects on earth, which should be more than enough to fill the rosters of all $36$ clubs.

Comment: I knew I was stepping over some social boundary or other.

Answer (score 1):

My general advice is to try and solve this for small $n$ first. For me, it also helped to assume that friendship has to be an equivalence relation. Then the friendship rule becomes "every club must contain exactly one person from every equivalence class of friends", which might be easier to grasp.

*Hint*:

We can regard every person as a subset of the set of clubs. Since "no two people are in the same set of clubs", every person is a different subset.
So what we have to do is, find as large as possible a set of subsets of an $n$-set such that we can assign friendship in a way satisfying the rules and maximizing the largest club.

*Solution*:

> Fortunately, we can just take all the subsets and say every set is friends with their complement set, so this setting should also give you the correct maximum size. Also note that we did not even have to assume that friendship is symmetrical nor does it matter whether a person must be friends with *at least* or *exactly* one person in every club they are not in. Of course, we also dropped the assumption that friendship has to be an equivalence relation. It just happens to be one in the solution.

Comment: Friendship is an equivalence relation?  If A is a friend of B and B is a friend of C then A is a friend of C?  Friendship is an equivalence relation but it's not symmetric?

Comment: No, it does not have to be. But assuming that it is actually made the problem easier for me. After you solved that, you can return to the original problem.

Comment: The question asks for the maximum size of a club.  You show a solution where each club is of size $1$, and claim that that is the only solution, without a vestige of justification.

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. I show a solution where adding a person immediately violates "No two people are in the same set of clubs". That is why the clubs are max size. Also, the size of the clubs is not 1, but $2^{n-1}$. If you tell me where I failed to explain this I will try to clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand.  How does $2^{n-1}$ arise?  What does it mean to say "Every set is friends with their complements set?"  Friends are persons, not sets of persons.  There are supposed to be $n=36$ clubs.  What are they?

Comment: I consider the set of clubs, which is just an $n$-element set. Then I identify a person with the set of clubs they are in. So the statement "Every set is friends with their complements set?" means, for every person there is a person who is in all the clubs the first person is not in and these two are friends.

Comment: Oh and $2^{n-1}$ is then just the number of subsets containing a given element.

Comment: I think I understand now.  Please edit your answer so I can reverse my downvote.